# Publish Media content data to omni channel

Tags: releasing-data

This is a very common scenario. 
What is the best way to implement publishing media content (Audio or Video) to different channel for same user?
e.g. If an user access a particular content in desktop and then close/pause the same and try to open in another channel say iPad. How the same content gets served and ensure where the user stops earlier and where to start with?
Moreover how to publish the media content at large scale?

Comment: This sounds to me like my typical YouTube usage, not an open data question. Would you mind to rephrase?